# Unable to get MySQL Connector/NET to work on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, mysql, ubuntu, mono

**General info**
Working on a game server running on Ubuntu (20.04.2 LTS). The game was made in Unity3D (C# / Mono). It's not my game, but it does allow users to mod. Game is Valheim, using BepInEx to inject DLL files written in C#.

**What I'm trying to do**
I'm trying to make a simple mod that connects to a MySQL database to store player data (players that connect to the server).

**The problem**
After downloading the MySQL Connector/NET (Mono version) and just testing very basic code, I keep running into the error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.

**What I tried to solve the problem**
I googled the issue which didn't really help much. All I could figure out was that maybe I need to install Mono on the server. So I did `sudo apt-get install mono-complete`. But that made no difference at all. The error is still there. So is there anyone perhaps able to shed some light on the problem for me and how to solve it?

**The code I used to test**

```
using BepInEx;
using System;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using UnityEngine;

namespace MySQLTest
{
    [BepInPlugin(PluginGUID, PluginName, PluginVersion)]
    public class MySQLTest : BaseUnityPlugin
    {
        public const string PluginGUID = "icecub.MySQLTest";
        public const string PluginName = "MySQLTest";
        public const string PluginVersion = "0.0.1";

        private string connectionString =
          "Server=localhost;" +
          "Database=REDACTED;" +
          "User ID=REDACTED;" +
          "Password=REDACTED;" +
          "Pooling=false";

        private void Awake()
        {

            IDbConnection dbcon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            dbcon.Open();
            IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();

            string sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
            dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
            IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string userName = (string)reader["username"];
                Debug.LogWarning($"Got the following data from the MySQL database: {userName}");
            }
            // clean up
            reader.Close();
            reader = null;
            dbcmd.Dispose();
            dbcmd = null;
            dbcon.Close();
            dbcon = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
Installed Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.8 as well, but still the same problem.

Comment: What version is in your .csproj file? Try to make `dotnet clean` & `dotnet restore` and try again

Comment: Try uninstalling MySql.Data and switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ instead; it has much better support for Mono, Xamarin, etc.